# How to exclude rows from dataframe that match rows in same column of another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

So I want to filter out certain rows in first dataframe also present in second dataset. The command below doesn't make a dataframe I desire.

`newdf <- filter(df1, df1$organization_name != df2$organization_name)`

Is there an alternative that works?

Comment: Maybe you need `%in%`. Try `newdf <- filter(df1, !organization_name %in% df2$organization_name)` Also read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
newdf <- filter(df1, !df1$organization_name %in% df2$organization_name)

###or using the pipe command:

newdf <- df1 %>%
filter(!df1$organization_name %in% df2$organization_name)
```

Some people prefer the "anti-join" function by the above suggestions are simpler and would do the trick

Comment: It works, thanks!